# How can I use SpEL inside an orm.xml?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I need to use an orm.xml file inside my Spring app, I'm creating a bean by doing the following:

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setPackagesToScan("org.mitre");
        bean.setPersistenceProviderClass(PersistenceProvider.class);
        bean.setDataSource(hikariDataSource);
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaAdapter);

        Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "INFO");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.logging.level.sql", "INFO");
        jpaProperties.put("eclipselink.cache.shared.default", "false");

        bean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties);
        bean.setPersistenceUnitName("defaultPersistenceUnit");

        switch (databaseType){
            case oracle: bean.setMappingResources("db/oracle/entity-mappings_oracle.xml"); break;
            case mssql: bean.setMappingResources("db/mssql/entity-mappings_mssql.xml"); break;
        }

        return bean;
    }
```

Down the bottom you can see me setting the mapping resources by providing a path to the resource on the classpath. However within my orm.xml I have the following:

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema>${some.schema.name}</schema>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>

</entity-mappings>
```

I need Spring to expand that property as the schema name will be configurable.

One possibility is to take the resource, find and replace the property myself and then output it to the file system. The problem here is that setMappingResources takes a string path to the Resource so it can't be on the file system.

Another possibility was creating an in-memory resource using ByteArrayResource like so:

```
case mssql: bean.setMappingResources("db/mssql/entity-mappings_mssql.xml");
                String localResource = IOUtils.readFileToString(mssqlMappings.getFile(), Charset.defaultCharset());
                Resource resource = new ByteArrayResource(localResource.replaceAll("${some.schema.name}" ,dbName).getBytes());
                bean.setMappingResources(resource.getFile().getPath());
                break;
```

However that doesn't work as mapping resources requires a path which a ByteArrayResource cannot provide.

Is there someway I can replicate the orm.xml in Java Config, where I can inject the property? I'm open to suggestions on alternative ways to do this.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use SpEL inside the `orm.xml` there is no Spring involved only JPA and JPA doesn't allow you to do that. Hibernate has a property which you can use to set the default schema. EclipseLink probably has something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change schema programmatically you can do it using SessionCustomizer, and add it to your jpa properties `jpaProperties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_CUSTOMIZER, YourSessionCustomizer);`

in YourSessionCustomizer you can change the schema in customize method

```
session.getLogin().setTableQualifier("your_schema")
```

Comment: Perfect, that's working!

For my JpaProperties I had to do the following:
        jpaProperties.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.SESSION_CUSTOMIZER, SchemaSessionCustomizer.class.getCanonicalName());

It's worth noting that the String the properties takes is the full canonical path to the class.

Comment: And to get a configurable property into the object, you can put it into the jpaProperties and then retrieve it from the session on the other side.